# How to order a IQueryable with null value in .net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

On the main page of my store there is a list of IQueryable that changes through different filters.
Now, for example, if the discounted price is null, the output at the time of orderBy will be equal to the error. I put part of the code ...

```
IQueryable<Group> result = _context.Groups
            .Include(c => c.Product)
            .Include(c => c.ProductGroup);
```

In the code below, output is received using another service

```
switch (getType)
        {
            case "all":
                break;
            case "discountPrice":
                result = IsDiscountedProductsByGroups(result);
                break;
        }
```

The error is seen below when trying to OrderBy. After this step, other filters will be applied and then filled in a ViewModel and the return value is Tuple.

```
if (getType == "discountPrice")
        {
            switch (orderByType)
            {
                case "date":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderByDescending
                            (p => p.Product.CreateDate)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Product.TireDiameter.Code);
                        break;
                    }
                case "lowPrice":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderBy(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Product.TireDiameter.Code);
                        break;
                    }
                case "highPrice":
                    {
                        result = result.OrderByDescending(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Product.TireDiameter.Code);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Edited question:

Added section:

The friends who commented seem to have thought that the products might not be price. But I have to say no.
The price is discounted but may start or end.
For this reason, when this list send to the following service, it gives a null answer and will encounter an error when orderBy:

```
public IQueryable<Group> IsDiscountedProductsByGroups(IQueryable<Group> groups)
    {

        foreach (var item in groups)
        {
            if (item.Product.PurchasePrice != null)
            {
                if (item.Product.StartDiscountTime != null && item.Product.StartDiscountTime < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    if (item.Product.EndDiscountTime != null && item.Product.EndDiscountTime > DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        listDiscountedProductsByGroup.Append(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return listDiscountedProductsByGroup;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include products that may, or may not have prices, and treat those without prices as 0, (or any other value) try something like this:

```
result.OrderBy(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.HasValue ? p.Product.PurchasePrice.Value : 0);
```

If you want them put at the end of the list, you could use a very large magic number in place of the "0" above, or better:

```
result.OrderBy(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.HasValue ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.HasValue ? p.Product.PurchasePrice.Value : 0);
```

This would order the ones that have a price by price, then move the ones lacking a price to the end.

If you want to exclude products that don't have purchase prices then you need to use a `Where` clause to filter them out.

```
result.Where(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.HasValue)
     .OrderBy(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.Value);
```

Update: ok, based on your updated implementation, there are a couple issues:

#1. from your example it's not clear where listDiscountedProductsByGroup is declared.

#2. There appears to be a bug in your date comparison logic where both Discount Start and End are expected to be Less than Now. Typically this would be Start <= now && End >= now.

#3. your "IsDiscountedProductsByGroups" method is taking an EF IQueryable, and will potentially return a materialized set of entities which may be IQueryable, but will no longer derive down to SQL, but be processed in memory. This isn't so much an issue if all you do is apply sorting, but if you want to apply any other filtering or paginate the results with `Skip`/`Take` this breaks the EF optimization to send to SQL.

Instead, this is possibly what you are looking for:

```
IQueryable<Group> result = _context.Groups
        .Include(c => c.Product)
        .Include(c => c.ProductGroup);

if (getType == "discountPrice")
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    result = result.Where(x => x.Product.PurchasePrice != null
        && x.Product.StartDiscountTime.HasValue 
        && x.Product.StartDiscountTime < now
        && x.Product.EndDiscountTime.HasValue 
        && x.Product.EndDiscountTime > now);
}
```

... then from here append the appropriate OrderBy. This will ensure the `IQueryable` remains an EF Queryable.

This assumes that you only want items that have a Product with a with a discount that today falls under. This looks a bit odd though as I'd expect a product would have more of a price history, or the idea of discounts would be tracked separately.

Comment: Your explanation was complete, but unfortunately you mistake my question. The question was corrected

Comment: I've added an update which may cover the scenario your updated example seems to be trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = result.OrderByDescending(p => p.Product.PurchasePrice.HasValue)
```

Comment: Added but I did not see any change and I still see an error